# What should be 'y_train' in Keras LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I refer to the example given at the Keras website [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

data_dim = 16
timesteps = 8
num_classes = 10

# expected input data shape: (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True,
       input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(32))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Generate dummy training data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, timesteps, data_dim))
y_train = np.random.random((1000, num_classes))

# Generate dummy validation data
x_val = np.random.random((100, timesteps, data_dim))
y_val = np.random.random((100, num_classes))

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

For a real-world example, what should be y_train and y_val? Should they be the same as x_train and x_val respectively, since they come from the same sequence?

Also, how should I understand data_dim and num_classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-univariate-time-series-data-long-short-term-memory-networks/) sort of answers my question.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

`'y_train'` and `'y_val'` should be whatever it is you are trying to predict. They can be values, classes, or they can be a sequence. The form of what you are trying to predict will influence how you structure a RNN in Keras: [Many to one and many to many LSTM examples in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43047615/9214357).

`'data_dim'` is the number of features in the dataset. If you are predicting the weather, the features may be 'pressure', 'temperature, 'precipitation', and so `'data_dim' = 3`.

`'num_classes'` is the number of classes that the outcome variable can assume. If the outcome variable is `'type of animal'`, and the classes the outcome variable can assume are `'dog'`, `'cat'`, `'bird'`, then `'num_classes' = 3`.

Comment: Is `y_train` supposed to have the same shape as `x_train` ?

Comment: Not generally. The row (or example) dimension should be the same but otherwise, the shapes will not typically be the same. If you are trying to predict a sequence, then that dimension can sometimes be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no necessity that Y_out should be of same shape as input sequence . however  u must predict  for each  input u have given
For ex lets say  u have a data with 2 samples each sample is basically a sequence with 4 time steps
i.e [2,3,4,5],[3,5,7,9]
the above problem will have two output for each sequence ,the out put could be the next val or next series of value whatever u want
the above can be think of as 1 sample with 8 time steps
i.e [2,3,4,5,3,5,7,9] in this case we  have 1 out put could be anything(next value or multiples  value)
dimension basically represent the feature of the input data in other word at a given observation in a time step what have u  got
classes represent the different categories Y out can belongs to.